# formatting TreeItem Text colour?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on Eclipse plugin. Here i created a separate view and now i want to format the color of tree node.

These are code present in createpartcontrol method.

```
ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL );
  Composite composite1 = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
  Composite composite_1 = creatingcomposite(composite1);
  Tree tree = new Tree(composite_1,  SWT.FULL_SELECTION );

   TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
```

here i want to set some colour like blue.

```
item.setText("This is sparta");
```

Now here i want some different colour like yellow on subsubitem text.

```
TreeItem subsubItem = new TreeItem(subItem, SWT.NONE);
subsubItem.setText(new String[] { "Function Name:          "+ errorPreTest11.description.get(j).function });
```

For doing this i tried to set SWT.COLOR_BLUE but it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
item.setForeground(tree.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
```

You can also create your own colors but if you do this you must dispose of them when you are done.

Comment: Thanks greg-449 when ever i stuck with plugin u are always there for help. :)

Comment: How can we bold the character?

Comment: There is nothing specific for bold, you have to use `setFont` with a suitable font.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using the `TreeViewer`. In this case you would have a functionality to set a `LabelProvier` on your viewer. Label provider has a subclass called `StyledCellLabelProvider`, which you can successfully extend to provide styling of your labels like this: (Please also see a [TextStyle](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/TextStyle.html) class for more formating options).

```
public class MyStyledLabelProvider extends StyledCellLabelProvider {

private Styler defaultStyler;
public MyStyledLabelProvider () {
        defaultStyler = new Styler() {
            @Override
            public void applyStyles(TextStyle textStyle) {
                textStyle.strikeout = true;
            }
        };
    }

@Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
        Object element = cell.getElement();
        StyledString styledString = getStyledString(element);
        cell.setText(styledString.toString());
        cell.setStyleRanges(styledString.getStyleRanges());
        super.update(cell);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private StyledString getStyledString(Object element) {
        return new StyledString("Cell string", defaultStyler);
    }
}
```